# Sass duplicate "classes" when nesting multiple @use in a structured code

Tags: css, sass, react-hooks

Hi everyone I have noticed that SASS doesn't seem clever enough to understand to don't duplicate code imported (or maybe I am missing something in the way that I have planned my code architecture).

Here is my repository:

*Duplication of classes, if I try to insert a class in one of the .scss that I import the most*
[image: Duplication of classes]

My CSS code is structured in this way, trying to following a standard of loading the code

My architecture
[image]

*FILE main.scss*

```css
// ITCSS: https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/

// Variable configurations for things like colors, fonts, sizes, etc…
@use "./01-settings.scss" as *;

// Globally used mixins and functions
@use "./02-tools.scss" as *;

// CSS resets and normalizing rules to create a foundation for your styles
@use "./03-generic.scss" as *;

// Style rules for bare HTML elements (like h1 or button)
@use "./04-elements.scss" as *;

// Load generic elements that are used in layouts
@use "./05-objects.scss" as *;

// Define basic values for main layout to make it responsive
@use "./06-media-queries.scss" as *;
```

Because the code is split, I have than inside of various of the element recall some includes once again otherwise SASS is not able to recognise the different variables or functions that I am using across the project.

*FILE @01-settings.scss*

```css
@use '00-load-fonts' as *;
@use '02-tools' as *;

// VARIABLES

// --BREAKPOINTS
$break-mobile:toRem(576);
$break-tablet-potrait:toRem(768);
$break-tablet-landscape:toRem(992);
$break-desktop:toRem(1200);
$break-desktop-l:toRem(1440);
$break-desktop-xl:toRem(1920);

// --SPACING
$space-xxl: toRem(48);
$space-xl: toRem(32);
$space-l: toRem(24);
$space-m: toRem(16);
$space-s: toRem(8);
$space-xs: toRem(4);
$space-xxs: toRem(2);

...etc...
```

*FILE @04-elements.scss*

```css
@use '01-settings' as *;
@use '02-tools' as *;

// GENERIC
html{height:100%;}
.body{background:var(--bg); color:var(--color-txt); min-height:100%;}

// LINK
a{text-decoration:none; color:$color-link;}
a:visited{color:$color-link-visited;}
a:hover, a:focus{text-decoration:underline;}
a:active{color:$color-link-active;}

// TYPOGRAPHY
.body{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: $font-family-primary;
    font-size: $font-size-m; 
    line-height: $line-height-m;
}

..etc...
```

My files have different kind of generic variables and function that I use across the SASS/React project so that I can have everything very customisable.

I clearly understand that this cause an issue of duplication because I am loading multiple time the same files, but it is really rubbing me the wrong way in having CSS that duplicates and there is not a way to filter it.

- is there a way to configure sass so that its be able to load classes once?
- or is there a way to structure so that this doesn't happen while retaining the ability of having smaller file with specific code instead of a BIG SINGLE FILE?
- any other suggestion/tip/idea that I am not aware?

I am sure that there are some kind of best practices that I am not aware about REACT & SASS, or probably a common solution for a common problem.

p.s. I would like if possible to maintain the ITCSS structure. [Here the article on the reason why is useful](https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/)

Comment: It looks like it's doing exactly what would be expected. The only imports/use you want are like variables, mixins, functions, since they don't transpile as per the first paragraph of the [@use docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use). When you import/use a file that has its own CSS already it would be expected to be duplicated so this unfortunately qualifies as a pebkac issue.